# How to calculate the external work of plastic deformation due to wire drawing (the work done by the wire drawing machine)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am currently trying to process some data from a wire drawing (cold drawing) test. I would like to know how I can calculate the external work of plastic deformation due to wire drawing, which is basically the work done by the wire drawing machine.

The data that I have are the length and diameter of the brass wire before and after each wire drawing operation (brass was drawn 3 times) as well as the time and force data for the wire drawing operations.

Any form of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break your elongation in two parts and calculate the work done separately, while measuring the diameter repeatedly.

The elastic part work is the force your machine is pulling multiplied by the elongation.

The plastic part it is the sum of incremental area measurements multiplied by the yield stress Fy times the particular section elongation or if your sample does not have a pronounced flat area again what the machine gouge reads.

Comment: Also the losses of the machine need to be evaluated, if the "work done" is the total work.

Comment: Thanks for both of your helpful advice. So, @kamram , what do you mean by the incremental area measurements ? I am trying to calculate the external work of plastic deformation after each drawing operation (total of 3 draws), so would the area used to calculate the plastic part be the area after each wire drawing operation?